# UIScrollView problem, scrolls just on one side

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm fairly new to programming, and I have looked for an answer for a very long time. There are some posts about it, but nothing has solved my problem. I have a `UIScrollView` view that I get from the nib, everything is ok with this, the content length is good and scrolling works, but it just scrolls on the left side, if I try to scroll on the right side it doesn't scroll..

Here is the code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSString *descriptionString = _currentBook.description; 
    CGSize stringSize = [descriptionString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(387, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 
    _authorLabel.text = _currentBook.author; 
    _titleLabel.text = _currentBook.title; 
    _descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description: %@",_currentBook.description]; 
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(387, stringSize.height +50)];
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post some code to help you

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *descriptionString = _currentBook.description;
    CGSize stringSize = [descriptionString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(387, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    
    _authorLabel.text = _currentBook.author;
    _titleLabel.text = _currentBook.title;
    _descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description: %@",_currentBook.description];
    
    
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(387, stringSize.height +50)];

}

Comment: @Nekto here is my ViewDidLoad code, very simple, and i still can't find the answer..

Comment: @Lukas For readability, try editting the original question instead of pasting the code in a comment.

Comment: @Nekto ok thanks, will do that in the future posts

Comment: did you implemented the method: - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView?

Comment: Ok, how do you determine that it doesn't scroll to left?

Comment: it doesn't scroll on the right side, not TO the right side. It scrolls up and down, but if i grab left side and drag it down/up it scrolls, but if i grab right side and try scrolling up or down, it doesn't scroll.. Maybe i didn't make my question clear, sorry for that, my native language is not english..

Comment: @meronix no, but i think it is not necessary. Am i wrong?

Comment: @lukas: no, you are right, it's not necessary, but it may help you to understand the strange behavior (just to test it... you can log the direction of the scroll and other things...)

Comment: @meronix I've done that, but it's not very useful, because the scrolling event doesn't occur at all there.. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @lukas: mhm... well... than that should tell you a lot! the event should be called, if not something is wrong! anyway, to use it, you should set your UIViewController with the <UIScrollViewDelegate> protocol (in your .h file), if not that method won't be called...

Comment: @meronix I've set the delegate, but event comes just then if i tap on the left side of the view and scroll, but not on the right side of the view.. I think the best solution would be to redo this from scratch, maybe then it will work correctly because i don't know what to do anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found my problem, I've added a uiview programmatically as a subview to some view and then to this View i've added my scroll view as a subview.. And then it would only scroll in the area of my UIView. It was nonsense to do it like this, still a lack of knowledge..
Thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to understand the problem since we cant see your nib file, but its better practice to put the scrollView on top the view of the view controller, and connect it to an IBOutlet in your view controller.

In order to find the problem I would get rid of the textfields for testing purposes (I think the constrained 9999 might be a problem but I am not sure) and then print and post the frame of the scrollView and the Content size in runtime.I am betting that you will see some issue with the frame of the uiscrollview.

Thanks,

Comment: in the past i didn't have problems with the 9999 constrains, and i did it a couple of times, i have checked the frame and it is as it should be. It's one thing i did different than other times, at first my UIScrollView was a UIView, in interface builder i've changed it's class from UIView in UIScrollView in identity inspector. Maybe it's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after copy-pasting and running some tests, I found out the problem.

The problem is in the wording of the question, your problem is not that the "scroll doesn't work on the right side" (As in: you move your finger up and down on the right side of the screen without triggering a scroll), the problem is that the contents, the label itself is going out of bounds, outside of the visible area of the scrollView, and the right-handed side is not visible.

First of all, you should note that the iphone resolution is 320x480 (640x960 for Retina), so you actually have to work with a smaller width (using 387 width will make it go out of bounds).

Second, take in account the x position of the label itself is also affecting the amount of visible text. With this in mind, a more generic code would be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This number represents the total width of the label that will fit centered in
    // the scrollView area.
    CGFloat visibleWidth = self.view.frame.width - descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x*2;

    // Use the number above to get a more accurate size for the string.
    NSString *descriptionString = _currentBook.description; 
    CGSize stringSize = [descriptionString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(visibleWidth, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    // Fill data (why so many underscores?)
    _authorLabel.text = _currentBook.author; 
    _titleLabel.text = _currentBook.title; 
    _descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description: %@",    _currentBook.description]; 

    // Also, why didn't you resize the description label? I'm assuming that you forgot this.
    // (Make sure that the descriptionLabel number of lines is 0)
    CGRect frame = descriptionLabel.frame;
    descriptionLabel.frame.size = stringSize;

    // Now set the content size, since you're using the scrollView as the main view of the viewController,
    // I'll asume that it's using the whole screen, so I'm gonna use the whole width
    // of the screen (that's what UIScreen is for).
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, stringSize.height +50)];
}
```

Comment: yes ,the wording of the question is a bit wrong, as i said my native language is not english, sorry. I agree the frame is bad, but I did it just for testing, because, when the frame is good, it still doesn't scroll if i grab the right side and try to scroll down/up. Currently i focus only on scrolling, not about if my whole text is visible on screen or not, the scrolling issue is still there.. it is very strange and it never occured to me before. Why it scrolls if i grab the left side, and doesn't scroll if i grab right side and try to scroll? Is it more clear now? Thanks for all the help

Comment: oh and as you said "(As in: you move your finger up and down on the right side of the screen without triggering a scroll)". It really is that way, it doesn't trigger an event if i try to scroll on the right side..